# How to integrate call/Incoming/call with WearOS?

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wearables

We have a call(VoIP) capability in our phone app and wanted to integrate in our  Wear/Watch App. We see from other apps like WhatsApp, etc the call channel is given to the Native Incoming/OutGoing call handle in the watch. We would like to know how do we integrate call channel with Wear app. We could not find much of information in Wear Documentation.

Comment: You should be able to use pretty much the same code as you do for your android app

Comment: Thanks for the response @Turtlepaw, we got to know that it is not same implementation how we do on phone, Phone app has to redirect/pass/addCall incoming call with to the Connected Clients, this is something to do with Telephoney api > ConnectionService. Android recently released new Lib which will extend many of the Telephoney APIs wrt connected devices or in general. Will update once we have conclusion on this.